# How to use URL hack in lightning to clone all fields EXCEPT recordtype, which i want to change

Tags: apex, button, url

I need to create a custom button that clone's a Lead record, and prepopulates all of the fields, EXCEPT that it needs to create it as a different record type. Here are a couple things I've tried for my url-hack-code, but neither work:

1. /{!Lead.Id}/e?&RecordType=0121N0000012oypQAA&clone=1

- this one "edits" the record and changes it to a new record type, but it is not doing my need of "creating new" record

2. /lightning/o/Lead/new?recordTypeId=0121N0000012oypQAA&
   defaultFieldValues=name='{!Lead.Name}',firstname={!Lead.FirstName},lastname={!Lead.LastName},OwnerId={!Lead.OwnerId}

- This one opens a "create new" record screen, but it is not prepopulating any of those fields. Plus, with this method I would need to manually go through each field that I want to prepopulate which may be way more busy-work than is really needed if there is a better way to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it in my DevOrg, seems like case -sensitive might be the issue.

Change name to Name ,firstname to FirstName......
Try it

```
/lightning/o/Lead/new?recordTypeId=0121N0000012oypQAA& defaultFieldValues=Name={!Lead.Name},FirstName={!Lead.FirstName},LastName={!Lead.LastName},OwnerId={!Lead.OwnerId}
```

Comment: I just tried it with the case-sensitive code but it is still not prepopulating those fields...

Comment: nevermind when I tried it there was a space between & and defaultFieldValues. When I closed that gap it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: How would I prepopulate lookup fields? I am trying this: InsuranceCompany__c={!Lead.InsuranceCompany__c}   but a strange thing is happening and the insurance company field is vanishing from the new record screen..

Comment: Hi Rick... I too have faced similar situation with Lookup fields before, seems there is some limitation reference: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007Pid

Comment: Thank you. I just created formula fields that take the id of the lookup fields and prepopulated with those formulas and that seems to do the job.