# URL Hack in the salesforce

Tags: url, urlhacking

I have two object one is Mandate__c and another one is Literature_distribution__c ,, in which i have one button with URL on the mandate to create the literature_distribution.....I jst need to copy the mandate record id from which the button is clicked should be default populated on the literature distribution page layout before creation.

for ex: Mandate_Name__c is lookup on the Literature_distribution__c ,, if user clicks on the MandateA(record)   then on the Page layout it should be prepopulated on the Mandate_name__c..

below is the formula i tried :
Value is not getting prepopulated , kindly help:

```
    /lightning/o/Literature_Distribution__c/new?&recordTypeId=01220000000AJdiAAG& defaultFieldValues=Literature_Distribution__c={!Literature_Distribution__c.RecordTypeId},
{! Literature_Distribution__c.Mandate_Name__c }={!Mandate__c.Id}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like default value for lookup field are not supported.

Check this:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007Pid

Check comment on my answer on below link in which user face similar issue with lookup field for URL hack:

[How to use URL hack in lightning to clone all fields EXCEPT recordtype, which i want to change](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344364/how-to-use-url-hack-in-lightning-to-clone-all-fields-except-recordtype-which-i/344377#344377)

suggested workaround by him

> created formula fields that take the id of the lookup fields and
> prepopulated with those formulas

Update:

I replicated this:

this seems working:

> /lightning/o/Literature_distribution__c/new?
> &defaultFieldValues=Mandate_Name__c={!Mandate__c.Id}

Comment: can you please explain a bit...formula fields needs to be created on Source ???

Comment: yes ..and that field will hold the Id of lookup field, in URL hack you have to map this formula field value instead of lookup.

Comment: If earlier it was something like this InsuranceCompany__c={!Lead.InsuranceCompany__c}   now it can be InsuranceCompany__c={!Lead.FormulaField__c}

Comment: can some one please give the straight forward answer?

Comment: I tried with the Formula field it is not working..kindly suggest another approach.

Comment: Have updated the answer. I would suggest start with that formula itself and test it.  When you will be adding other field keep a check on extra space ,if extra space is there in between it affect the result. keep a check on upper case and lower case.As I can see on your post you have mentioned Literature_distribution__c however in formula you have used Literature_Distribution__c.